# C - Initializing an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to initialize an array of pointers but when i try to print it in the main it don't work, It shows an segmentation fault but if i try to print it in the same method it do print

here is my code

```
typedef struct File
{
    char fileName[Max_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
    char *listOfFiles[];
}File;

File dependencies[MAXIMUM_FILES];

void findListOfFiles(char *line, int i, int currDepend)
{
int idx=0,numOfFiles=0;;
while(line[i]!='\n')
{
    char *name=(char *)malloc(65*sizeof(char));
    while(line[i]!=',' && line[i]!='\n')
    {
        name[idx]=line[i];
        i++;
        idx++;
    }
    name[idx]='\0';
    dependencies[currDepend].listOfFiles[numOfFiles]=name;
    printf("%s+", dependencies[currDepend].listOfFiles[numOfFiles]);
    if(line[i]=='\n')
    {
        if(name){
            free(name);
            name=NULL;
        }
        break;
    }
    if(name){
        free(name);
        name=NULL;
    }
    numOfFiles++;
    i++;
    idx=0;
}
}
```

Comment: Is listOfFiles properly allocated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually allocate space for the `listOfFiles` member anywhere. This means that this array is, essentially, of size zero so all writing to any entry in it will be out of bounds.

If you want `dependencies` to be a global variable, you have to either set a fixed size for the `listOfFiles` array, or make it a pointer-to-pointer and allocate/reallocate when needed.

Also, after you assign the pointer `name` to the array, you then `free` this allocated memory, meaning the pointer now in the array points to free'd memory.

Comment: now after i put the array of size 100 and, when i tried to print it it prints nothing